# How to add a status field to a dictionary output?

Tags: python

I need to write a python API for users to call. The input and output specifications are below, as one example:

```
// input
{"keyword":"iPhone", 
 "category":"phone"
}

// output
{
"keyword": "iPhone", 
"status": "success", 
"result": [
 {
 "word": "iPhone", 
 "type": "smart_phone"
 }, "extend":{} 
          ]
}
```

I am not going to write http service, but just regular python function for call, and the user needs to install:

```
pip install my_api
```

The input is a dictionary, and the output is also a dictionary. How to populate the 'status' field in the output dictionary? I feel this is required for http service to indicate whether the call is successful or not. Since I am not using http service, I don't know how to generate value for the 'status' in the output. The function I write would look like:

```
def query_by_dict(input: Dict) -> Dict:

    result = {}
    ...
    result = self.query_helper(input)
    return result
```

if the self.query_helper() fails or didn't produce any value, I will just return an empty dict 'result' to the client. Why is the 'status' field in the output specification?

Comment: Just call `result['status'] = "<request status>"` just before you return the result from your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we know that `result` in the `query_by_dict` function is already a dictionary, we can just add another argument to that dictionary. As seen below:

```
def query_by_dict(input: Dict) -> Dict:

    result = {}
    ...
    result = self.query_helper(input)
    result['status'] = 'success' if result else 'failure'
    return result
```

In the above example, the important part of the code is the `result['status']` where we are defining the `status` argument of the result dictionary. Since we know an empty dictionary result is failure, we can just check for this and set the `status` argument.

Comment: But how to get the value of <desired status result>? It would be either 'success' or 'failure'. How do I know which one is used for each call? When the dict is empty, it's success, otherwise, failure. So is this field useful?

Comment: @marlon how about `results["status"] = bool(result) and "success" or "failure"`?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev, you mean first get False and True, and then convert them to success and failure?

Comment: yea why not? :) but IMO that's not much useful. just boolean is better

Comment: @marlon I updated my answer so that it's possible to get the status result.